# Is there a derivation of the Early effect?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

I can't seem to find a derivation of the following equation:

$$I_C=I_Se^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_{T}}}\left(1+\frac{V_{CE}}{V_A}\right)$$

Is there a way to derive this equation?

Edit: The equation describes a bjt transistor, so I have included a bjt. Also a plot of Ic against Vce to demonstrate the early effect.

[image: BJT]

[image: Plot of Ic against Vce]

Comment: If you are going to ask where equations come from, it is helpful to draw a circuit that the equation describes. Although some people will see some of the terms (such as Vbe, Vce) and be able to deduce what the equation is describing, some will just see it as useful as if you replaced everything with a, b, c, d etc. Please add some context to the question.

Comment: @MCG I have included the relevant circuit and a plot to illustrate the early effect.

Comment: Are you OK with the derivation of the ebers moll equation and the simplification used in your equation?

Comment: @Andyaka yes I understand

Comment: So, it's just the \$(1 + \frac{V_{CE}}{V_A})\$ bit that is problematic to you?

Comment: @Andyaka yes that part is the problem

Comment: @dilinex Of course there is a derivation from 1st principles. This can be performed at 1D and 2D approximations, and also at 3D levels. Are you interested in the seminar papers?

Comment: @jonk Any resource would be helpful.

Comment: @dilinex When I get a chance, I'll pull the articles for you.

Comment: @dilinex "J. M. Early, "Effects of Space-Charge Layer widening in Junction Transistors," Proceedings IRE, Vol. 40, pp 1401-1406, November, 1952.  J. M. McCalla, "Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Bandpass Amplifiers," university of California, Berkeley, Ph.D Disertation, June 1972. "Transition Region Capacitance of DIffused pn Juntions" IEEE trans. Electron Devices, voll ED-20, pp 290-298, March 1971. "P. E. Gray, et al, "Physical Electronics And Circuit Models of Transistors," SEEC Vol 2., Section 9.1, J. Wiley 1964. And A B Philips, "Transistor Enjineering, "Section 9.2, McGraw_Hill, 1962.

Comment: @jonk thank you

Comment: @dilinex It's all be done, long ago. You need to just back up and go to the 1950's (to see 1st principles development) and 1960's to see the model approximations that developed later (and why.) I had to do a complete 3D set of integrals to determine the behavior of a Hamamatsu photodiode for an application I was working on (and to do it, I had to reverse engineer the dopant concentrations as Hamamatsu refused to provide them.) It's not terribly complex. The Early Effect also has a less well-known Late Effect that made Dr. Early kind of miffed when the name became used. (Just another story.)

Comment: @dilinex If you want, I can provide a derivation process for you. It will involve some assumptions and a Taylor's expansion series and the derivation will expand over perhaps 4 or 5 printed pages to get there. But if you are seriously interested, I've been there, done that, and can reproduce things from old notes and references. Is it important to you?

Comment: @jonk I am trying to understand things from the ground up so this is why this derivation is important. If a derivation can be provided, I would be grateful if it isn't problematic to you.

Comment: @dilinex I'll need to get up the energy. Might not be today or tomorrow. The logic flows something like this: (1) starting assumptions and philosophy/theory discussion; (2) expression for the variation of the idea of basewidth obtained; (3) Early Voltage deduced to specific circumstances, mathematically ; (4) model parameters that strongly relate to basewidth modified appropriately; (5) geometrical interpretation explained. It's kind of a lot of work. And if you want this done in 3D, including handling surface charges, then... well... maybe a book would be better?

Comment: @dilinex The assumptions are benign, though. For example, I would assume the BJT is operating in a linear mode and that constant-doping is assumed to hold (though it never actually does in reality.) But since basewidth modulation is a 2nd order effect, those starting assumptions for a 1st order analysis is usually acceptable. Of course, if you want this to "go deep" then all the terms would need to be kept and the math gets very painful.

Comment: @dilinex I haven't forgotten. Have you read [the Early Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect)? It develops equations there. They don't result exactly the way you want, but they do provide the motivation well. I have a different approach that bypasses some of the complexity there. But actually, the topic needs to be treated both with constant \$I_\text{B}\$ curves as well as constant \$V_\text{BE}\$ curves to fully explain why it all works so well. There are large scale vs small scale (differential) views, too. Anyway, I estimate a very long answer. And it still may not help.

Comment: @jonk I have figured it out, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jonk..Because you have mentioned constant IB as well as constant VBE curves: Both approaches give different VA values. The problem is that in some books/papers the IB method and in some other contributions the VBE method is used for defining the Early voltage. Hence, we have two different definitions (the slopes of the Ic=f(VCE) curves are not equal in both cases) . What is your opinion - or do you have a final answer?

Answer (score 1):

If \$A\$ is the angle at A, and \$I_{CA}\$ is the current at \$V_{CE}=0\$ 
which approximately equals \$I_{C}\$ (with no Early effect), then

\$\tan(A) = I_{CA}/V_A\$

If \$\Delta I_{CA}\$ is the increase in the value of \$I_c\$ due to the Early effect then also,

\$\tan(A) = (I_{CA} + \Delta I_C ) / (V_A+V_{CE})\$

Now solve for \$(I_{CA}+ \Delta I_C)\$ you will get the above equation.

Comment: This answer would be better if formatted with MathJax.